# iOS 9 Bug when using presentViewController "EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2"

Tags: xcode, ios9

First. IT WAS working until this last update from Apple. So in theory it should still work.
Here's the code:

```
CarouselViewController *cViewController = [[CarouselViewController alloc] initWithContent: edition];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: cViewController];

[self presentViewController: nav animated: YES completion:nil];
```

The reason i'm doing it is because i need this new window to be presented in fullscreen and not inside this ViewController (the caller) which is occupying half of the screen.
So, HOW can i fix this? And why BEFORE it was working and now with this silly iOS 9 update it isn't?

Comment: Things change in updates, control flow usually changes. I'm guessing by the above that Apple may have fixed their own bugs that allowed your code to work. There's definitely not enough context to tell when you're presenting the VC and if you're validly presenting it. All because something used to work and doesn't work now doesn't mean Apple broke something.. it could very well mean they fixed something or adjusted control flow. If you're doing something obscure during the life cycle that doesn't follow recommended patterns, there's no guarantee that it won't break.

Comment: Yes i understand all of that, and still it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: What does the stack trace look like where it crashes?  What is the exception?

Comment: It only says: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code=2
And it crashes exactly at:

[self presentViewController: nav animated: YES completion:nil];

![Screenshot](http://s4.postimg.org/9pne9car1/Screen_Shot_2015_10_07_at_6_12_26_PM.png).

Comment: There is no exception information printed in the debug console?

Comment: I sent the screenshot link.. that's it: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code=2 .

Comment: I've been trying to track down a sporadic crash with presentViewController:animated:completion: for a UIActivityViewController. I just found this issue with iOS 9. Possibly related to your issue as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699622/ios-9-crash-when-presenting-uiactivityviewcontroller-uiview-fromwindoworient

Answer (score 0):

My guess (and that's all it is with the limited information presented) is that the root cause of the problem has something to do with `CarouselViewController` and it's view actually being loaded and presented on screen.
That is what is happening in your app during this line
 `[self presentViewController: nav animated: YES completion:nil]`

I would set a breakpoint in that ViewController subclass `loadView`/`viewDidLoad` or check out it's Nib/Storyboard.

Comment: I already checked the viewDidload.. it's never called. Not even viewWillAppear is ever called. Only the initWithContent wich is called and returned correctly with not errors.

Comment: I can even use the initiated CarouselViewController in different ways and it's shown.. but only inside the viewcontroller caller.. And what it needs to do is to open it fullscreen, like it was before with the original code

Comment: viewDidLoad would always be called before viewWillAppear.

Comment: What type of view controller is `self`? Perhaps you need to specify a `UIModalPresentationStyle`

Comment: self is a BaseViewController which is a UIViewController.. i'm using a Splitviewcontroller

Comment: How would UIModalPresentationStyle make any difference? Can you give more details?

Comment: My guess is somehow you're corrupting the view hierarchy by trying to present the UINavigationController from your BaseViewController. I don't know a whole lot about UISplitViewController if that is somehow involved. Is this an iPad only or Universal app? Apple has definitely changed some behaviors with the iOS 9 split screen multi-tasking on iPad.

Comment: It's only for iPad. And i don't see other way around to present this in fullscreen other than using this current code. Other ways don't work at all. That one used to.. not anymore